# Mesh artefacts/flickering with displace/deform modifier

Tags: displacement

I've run into a problem on numerous occasions when animating leaves/plants with modifiers to fake wind. The plants are bought (jungle scapes/blender market) so I'd guess that the mesh itself doesn't have issues - trunk is a mesh & leaves are images with transparency. Tried one approach with two simple deform modifiers stacked where the angle is controlled by noise. Looks good in the viewport, but when rendered the whole tree is flickering (see gif below). Weight painting the tree didn't fix this either.

[image]

Tried another approach with the displacement modifier - viewport looks good, render has way less artefacts but certain frames still glitch out.

[image]

I have no clue what is causing this, but it's very noticeable & distracting. Any help on how to fix this would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to render just with CPU (without GPU)? The re-rendering, that fixed the issue is wierd. I dont think anyone can answer you without seeing your .blend. Share simplified scene with just a part of tree that still generates the issue.

Comment: Sorry - I was wrong, the re-rendering didn't fix the issue. Turning motion blur off and then rendering the frames again worked. Is rendering with motion blur not ideal? Should it be added in post as a general rule?